# Background networking process

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, background-process

We are facing a ocasional problem, that we don’t know how can we solve it,

In our Xef app, when the waiter orders he presses a button to send the order to the kitchen,
then, the app saves the order to the server

This is done in two steps

1. Print to kitchen
2. When we get the OK or ERROR from the printer, we save the order to the server with the print status

The issue we are facing is that some users (iphone, ipod touch and ipad mini) press the power button just when step 1 is still performing (so they store the device in their pocket)

Therefore, the step 2 is not executed when the app is in background (step 1 completes sucesfully)

Do you have any idea or guidance if this is something possible to fix, and how could we do it?

Thank you so much.

Comment: can you plz show your tried code?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found how to solve it!

Before starting the process I call

```
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTaskId = [UIApplication.sharedApplication beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{

}];
```

And when I end the process I call

```
[UIApplication.sharedApplication endBackgroundTask:bgTaskId];
```

This way, iOS gives me up to 3 minutes for the printing/save actions to be finished

Answer (score 0):

Try making your session configuration as background.

Comment: what do you mean